# Reconnect whilst keeping state with netty 4

Tags: netty

I'm using netty 4 and make use of the `ChannelPipeline` to keep things like protocol state management separate from codecs (for example). This works really well - and I love the single threaded (when you want it) nature of the pipeline.

I also want to manage disconnects / reconnects.

But - when 'disconnected' - I want to persist messages that would have otherwise been sent to the dude who disconnected.
I'd like to do this whilst still making use of netty features (i.e. still using my handlers in the pipeline to do encoding etc prior to persistence).

Obviously though, this (logical) pipeline lives past the lifespan of one channel (when the reconnect occurs, I'll use a session name sent in a login message and pull all the state back in to the new channel's pipeline).

Obviously I can do it all outside of netty - but I still would love to carry on using the pipeline for encoding etc whilst disconnected.
All I can think of at the moment is using some kind of '/dev/null/' style (custom) channel which just drops everything while we're disconnected, with appropriate rebuilding of the pipeline on disconnect (where we'd switch in this 'fake' dead message channel) and reconnect, and a custom `EventExecutorGroup` to keep threading nice (i.e. pinned to the 'logical session' state - so moves around channel to channel). This seems a bit 'ugh' :)

Is there any kind of existing 'pattern' I haven't seen documented for handing the period between disconnect & reconnect whilst maintaining state and use of pipeline features in netty 4?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to ensure "best effort delivery" to client. I handle something similar to this.

Upstream you want a sink with a queue and a channel group attached. When the client connects one of these sinks is created and they are added to the channel group. When messages are added, they are added to both the queue and written to the channel group. Every connection in the group receives those messages.

On reconnect, you (magically) map the new client back to the sink, and (magically) determine what its position in the queue was, and send the delta from the queue, and add him to the group. The "magical" parts are up to you.

You do need to worry about concurrency in this code, and you have to worry about manual garbage collection of the sinks.

I'm a big fan of Guava for TTL and LRU caches, and I've used them in this context.

**Updated:**

Based on the clarifications below, you are asking to dynamically construct your pipeline and reuse handlers. Pipeline handlers can be reused, so **this [sequence diagram](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/cgi-bin/cdraw?lz=dGl0bGUgSGFuZGxlclJldXNlCgpDbGllbnQxLT5OZXR0eTogY29ubmVjdAoACgUtPllvdXJQaXBlbGluZUZhY3Rvcnk6IGNyZWF0ZQAPCAAXFDogaW52b2tlCgA0DABIBlNlc3Npb24AgH8HACAJYWN0aXZhdGUgABISAEAFACkOADUWZGV0ZWN0IG5ldyBjAIFSBQphbHQgaXMABwsgADgVU3RhdGVmdWwAgQwJbmV3IAAGDygpAG8ZAIFsCmFkZExhc3QoaACCXgYAHRYAgXsHTWFwOiBwdXQocwCCDAYsIAAYHgCBFBBzZW5kIG1lc3NhZ2UgdXBzdHJlYW0KZGUAgi4cAIJdCQCBYw8KAIFzDwCCABNkbyBidXNpbmVzcyBsb2dpYwBfDAA_EGVsc2UgW2lzIG9sZACDBQddAIMyMQCCHAxnZQCCHwkpCgCCNwotAIQ-FgCCeAcAgn00AIIJc25vdGUgb3ZlcgCEYxA6IHJldGFpbmVkIHN0YXRlIACCVlFuZCAK&s=vs2010)** should do basically what you want.

What's not included in that diagram are the external processes that are writing to the handler. When the ctx is detached and the connection is closed down stream, you'll need to handle the buffering to the client within your stateful handler. The exact mechanics I think you can experiment with.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - ChannelGroups definitely seem interesting. Not _quite_ sure they're what I'm after though (I'm probably misunderstanding!). See, I want a single pipeline doing various transformations / encoding. At a certain point in the pipeline I persist. Now, if connection goes down, I want to continue an the transforms / encoding / persist - but clearly not attempt to send to dead channel. Not single message -> multi channel (as wouldn't this duplicate encoding etc?). So still cant see a clean way other than new dummy channel creation upon 'channelUnregistered' notification :(

Comment: I suppose what I'm getting at is that the whole pipeline way of working seems quite rich and useful: And I'm hoping it doesn't all fall apart if you want to switch out the underlying 'Channel' - or have no (active) channel at all - whilst keeping the nice threading model etc. Otherwise, what probably happens is that more and more stuff moves 'up' a layer in the stack, and netty is just used to send pre-encoded (and persisted, in this case,) byte buffs.....

Comment: Updated the answer in response to your clarifications.

Comment: Yeah sounds much closer to what I want - thanks will give it a go. My worry is that I that as soon as the channel is closed, any write gets an immediate failed promise. Remember - I need outbound messages to go thru the pipeline even when the connection is down (so I can still do all the encoding / persistence still). That's why I suspected i might need a fake channel to run the pipeline when the connection is down. Or move the codecs / persistence out of netty handlers - which I feel would be a shame

Comment: The ChannelGroup would enable you to abstract away the channel state from the writer; e.g. contain a live connection and a buffering channel, so that writes to the group will write down through both; you store messages in the buffering channel if the live channel is closed. When you add a connection to group, you reach into the buffering channel and ask for its messages to run through the reconnected live channel.

Comment: _so that writes to the group will write down through both_: But this is exactly what I think I want to avoid :)  All my codecs etc live in the pipeline. I don't want to have to duplicate encoding (and any other amount of work) by going twice thru a pipeline. I want to go thru the pipeline, doing various transforms / encodings as I go - persist at the last point before I hit the wire, not duplicate work, and _still_ be able to write (maintaining state of my handlers) when the connection goes down. I'm not sure just writing to two channels helps here - unless I move stuff _out_ of the pipeline

Comment: There's nothing that forces you to have identical channel + pipelines in a channel group. The pipelines can be different. The live pipeline can do protocol encoding. The buffering channel/pipeline can do what it needs to do. As specifics matter, I can only say: this can work if you design it properly, such that encoding concerns are properly separated from buffering concerns. I recommend you do a sequence diagram to clarify the concerns of your pipeline. It could be you have one handler doing two jobs; ergo. make it two handlers.

Comment: And FYI, I have a netty service that services as many as 18k new http  requests per second comfortably on modest hardware. Duplicating encoding is probably a marginal concern.

Comment: I commend your persistence ;o) no - for me encoding is a big deal that I don't want to be duplicating. Im micros sensitive. It sort of feels to me that netty could just improve here in the pipeline department. If channels can come and go, but the pipeline is your execution context - the former shouldn't own the lifecycle of the later

Comment: (The 'buffered' content in my case is the raw encoded content I've got by going thru the pipeline - but put to disk)